# Python 3.5.1: How Do You Convert Each Number In A List To Tuples After They Were Appended To That List?

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-3.5

How I can convert each item in a list into tuples after they were appended to that list? I have this list:

```
Cards = []
```

I want to append 100 cards to the Card list without having to do this:

```
Card = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,...]
```

So I did this instead:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    Cards.append(i)
print(Cards)
```

And that gave me the result I was looking for which was:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Now, I want to convert each number into a tuple, I tried multiple things:

```
tuple(Cards)
```

and:

```
Cards = []
x = "()"
for i in range(1, 101):
    Cards.append(i)
x.join(Cards)
```

But none of them gave me:

```
[(1), (2), (3), (4),...]
```

How can I make ^ happen?

Comment: `(1)` is not a tuple. It's just `1` in grouping parentheses.

Comment: I think this question reads like a good question by a coding/python novice willing to learn. Personally I would not downvote it. Often the art of asking is inverse proportianl to the need to ask ;-)

Comment: @MorganThrapp: Because `i` is not iterable; it is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cards = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    Cards.append((i,))
```

Note that a tuple is usually 2 items, so when you print the array there will be an extra comma. Might be better to use a 1 dimensional array instead, ie:

```
Cards.append([i])
```

Comment: A list comprehension is usually the recommended and fastest way to create a list in these simple cases. Also the "note" in this answer is misleading at best IMO: A pair is usually 2 items, but a tuple may be 0, 1, ... N items. The difference (mainly) between a tuple and a list is, that a tuple is immutable whilst a list is mutable. The question before continuing with the coding project should be: Why a container inside a container if only one entry per "contained" container.

Answer (score 3):

Try a list comprehension for fast and pythonic list of single element tuples:

```
Cards = [(i,) for i in range(1, 101)]
```

Sample session:

```
>>> Cards = [(i,) for i in range(1, 101)]
>>> Cards
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (10,), (11,), (12,), (13,), (14,), (15,), (16,), (17,), (18,), (19,), (20,), (21,), (22,), (23,), (24,), (25,), (26,), (27,), (28,), (29,), (30,), (31,), (32,), (33,), (34,), (35,), (36,), (37,), (38,), (39,), (40,), (41,), (42,), (43,), (44,), (45,), (46,), (47,), (48,), (49,), (50,), (51,), (52,), (53,), (54,), (55,), (56,), (57,), (58,), (59,), (60,), (61,), (62,), (63,), (64,), (65,), (66,), (67,), (68,), (69,), (70,), (71,), (72,), (73,), (74,), (75,), (76,), (77,), (78,), (79,), (80,), (81,), (82,), (83,), (84,), (85,), (86,), (87,), (88,), (89,), (90,), (91,), (92,), (93,), (94,), (95,), (96,), (97,), (98,), (99,), (100,)]
```

In case one does not want to display the required comma, one could:

```
>>> for c in Cards: print '(%s),' % c[0],
... 
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39), (40), (41), (42), (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50), (51), (52), (53), (54), (55), (56), (57), (58), (59), (60), (61), (62), (63), (64), (65), (66), (67), (68), (69), (70), (71), (72), (73), (74), (75), (76), (77), (78), (79), (80), (81), (82), (83), (84), (85), (86), (87), (88), (89), (90), (91), (92), (93), (94), (95), (96), (97), (98), (99), (100),
```

But this is only display. The comma is necessary for a single element tuple literal to distinguish it from the "grouping" parentheses that allow you ege to write longer strings without an exploding right margin like so:

```
long_string = ("foobarbaz foobarbaz"
               " yes")
```

will result in `long_string` content:

```
"foobarbaz foobarbaz yes"
```

Comment: But there are commas inside of the parentheses and I don't want that.